# Adding a new can/light on same switch-controlled circuit as ceiling fan

Tags: switch, fans, recessed-lighting

Objective: to install a new can light fixture, to be controlled by an existing wall switch.  Original configuration: the wall switch supplies power to a ceiling fan with light kit.

What I did: I spliced the wires for the can fixture into one line of the existing circuit (14/2) between the switch and the fan. The result is that the wall switch continues to supply and control power to the old fan/light, BUT the light switch on the fan is also controlling the new can. Furthermore, the 3-way switch on the fan is dimming the new can with the differing degrees of fan speed.

Help needed: what should I do to correct the problem, so that the wall switch controls the new can and also supplies power to the fan, while the fan/light works correctly and independently as they did before?

I have not attempted to correct the situation by splicing into the *other* line in the existing circuit instead of the one I spliced into. It's all in the attic and I wanted to get input before dealing with all the fiberglass insulation and lack of lighting up there. Many thanks!

Comment: Pics of the wiring would help.  Your location in the world will let us know what type of wiring you're are dealing with.